# prove unique existence of a solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the differential equation $y'(t)=t^2 \cos(y(t)+\arctan t)-{1 \over (1+t^2)}$.

I want to prove the unique existence of the solution $y \in C^1(R)$.

$f \in C^0(R^2)$ so the solution exists on $R^2$.

But for the unique?

Answer (score 0):

Let $z(t) = y(t) + \arctan t$, then $z'(t) = y'(t) + \frac 1{1 + t^2}$, hence 
$$ z'(t) = t^2 \cdot \cos z(t) =: g(t, z(t)) \tag+ $$
as $g$ is locally Lipschitz, the solution of $(+)$ is locally unique.

Comment: why g is locally Lipschitz?